# ANDROID: How to select only one ImageView at a time?

Tags: android, imageview

I set four `ImageView` as a menu.
in four menu item i want to select only one at a time.

And i set the 2 Images for one Menu Item like 1 from selected and another 3 for Deselected.

here i posted the code:

**footer.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#f1eeee"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/fHome"
    android:src="@drawable/home" />  <!-- your image here -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/fAttendence"
    android:src="@drawable/home" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:src="@drawable/target" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:src="@drawable/report" />
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sachin.colorchanged.MainActivity">
<include
    layout="@layout/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/include2" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView mHomeButton,mattendence,mTarget,mReport;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHomeButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fHome);
        mattendence = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fAttendence);
        mTarget= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fTarget);
        mReport = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fReport);

        mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Set the button's appearance
                mHomeButton.setSelected(!mHomeButton.isSelected());
                if (mHomeButton.isSelected()) {
                    //Handle selected state change
                    mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                } else {
                    //Handle de-select state change
                    mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
                }

            }
        });
        mattendence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mattendence.setSelected(!mattendence.isSelected());
                if (mattendence.isSelected()) {
                    //Handle selected state change
                    mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                } else {
                    //Handle de-select state change
                    mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
                }
            }
        });
        mTarget.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTarget.setSelected(!mTarget.isSelected());
                if (mTarget.isSelected()) {
                    //Handle selected state change
                    mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                } else {
                    //Handle de-select state change
                    mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
                }
            }
        });
        mReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mReport.setSelected(!mReport.isSelected());
                if (mReport.isSelected()) {
                    //Handle selected state change
                    mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                } else {
                    //Handle de-select state change
                    mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

[[image: home.png for deselected item]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GRTk.png)[[image: blue.png for selected item]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BN65.png)

please help me out of this and  suggest me with the example..

Comment: and when will you able to select other images options?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma when i jumping to the next page

Comment: @Rahul Sharma have u seen the Facebook in ios application Excatly the same way i want to use in my application

Comment: and you are moving to next screen on the click of each imageview. Right?

Comment: @RahulSharma Excatly

Comment: You should use `Tabs` if you are wants to switch entire screen.

Comment: then simply call clicklistener on each imageview and open your new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make your class implement `View.OnClickListener` as:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

then implement the `onClick` method of the interface:

```
@Override
public void OnClick(View v)
```

Now in you `OnClick` method first load all the default images of the images like:

```
  mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
  mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.home); // and other imageViews
```

then define a `switch` case in onClick method as:

```
switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.fHome:
     mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
     break;
  // define same as all other views
}
```

The final code will be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView mHomeButton,mattendence,mTarget,mReport;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHomeButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fHome);
        mattendence = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fAttendence);
        mTarget= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fTarget);
        mReport = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fReport);

       mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
       mattendence.setOnClickListener(this);
       mTarget.setOnClickListener(this);
       mReport.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnClick(View v){
        mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        int selected = 0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,YOURACTIVITY.class);


        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.fHome:
            mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
            selected = 1;
            break;

        case R.id.mTarget:
            mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
            selected = 2;
            break;

        case R.id.fAttendence:
            mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
            selected = 3;
            break;


        case R.id.mReport:
            mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
             selected = 4;
            break;


      } 
      intent.putExtra("selected",selected);
      startActivity(intent);  
}
```

And then in your other activity you have to check which imageView was selected:

```
int selected = getIntent().getIntExtra("selected",0);
   switch(int){
   case 1:
     mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
     break;
   case 2 ... and so on
    }
```

Comment: @Sanoop  when i am moving to the next screen the color remains gray only..

Comment: @SachinSolanki Well am not the one who answered.. LOL

Comment: @Sanoop wokaie... do you have any idea for this??

Comment: @SachinSolanki i am not sure how are you using the same layout in the next activity.

Comment: @M.Waqas Pervez i created an xml file as a footer.xml 
and in every activity i called that file using 
<include
        layout="@layout/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/include2" />

Comment: you should be using this : https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar if you want a bottom bar. it will be hard to maintain your own layout. since you are using it in different activities

Comment: if you want to workout your own fotter. let me update my answer

Comment: this is what i came up with. hope you get the context

Comment: @M.Waqas Pervez i am using this 
public class Attendence extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
may be that's the reason ?

Comment: Since you are in fragment : use `getActivity().getIntent()`

Comment: already did this but now When i was moving to the next screen Image is deselected but i want it as a selected in particular screen